# Using defprotocol to create javascript object

Tags: clojurescript

Given I've defined a protocol

```
(defprotocol SubscriptionListener
  (onConnection [cid] "")
  (onUpdate [cid data] ""))
```

And I am interacting with a library in which a javascript object with this interface is passed in as follows

```
(js/somelib.connect url listener)
```

Is there an easy way to create a javascript object using the defined protocol?

I have tried to `reify` the protocol:

```
(js/somelib.connection "localhost" (reify SubscriptionListener
                                      (onConnection [cid] (println cid))
                                      (onUpdate [cid data] (println data))))
```

However this does not give an object that is compatible with external libraries.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a conceptual mismatch here. The js library already expects a defined behavior but you want to define it yourself from cljs. Should the listener be a js object with 2 methods, `onConnection` and `onUpdate`? Then you need some translator between your `SubscriptionListener` in cljs and a regular object in js:

```lisp
(defprotocol SubscriptionListener
  (on-connection [o cid])
  (on-update     [o cid data]))

(defn translator
  "Translates a cljs object that follows SubscriptionListener 
   into a js object that has the right mehods"
  [o]
  #js {:onConnection (fn [cid]      (on-connection o cid))
       :onUpdate     (fn [cid data] (on-update o cid data))})

(js/somelib.connection "localhost"
                        (translator (reify SubscriptionListener
                                      (on-connection [_ cid] (println cid))
                                      (on-update     [_ cid data] (println data))))
```

Notice that the functions in `SubscriptionListener` take the object that complies with the protocol as their first argument. If `cid` is some id given to you by the server and you tried to call `(on-connection cid)` you would get `Method on-connection not defined for integers`.